# How generate next id number for php mysql driven database

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert-update

I have a table `employees` which contains the details of employees in a firm.

Each one assigned a unique serial number. Whenever we add a new employee, it should display a serial number in adding form, which is one number greater than the serial number of the last entered employee.

For example, the database contains 12 employees. The serial number of the last entry is `12`. When I try to add new employee it should automatically assign the serial number `13`. So I don't need to enter serial number. How can I do this?

Comment: You're not using auto_increment on the employee serial number? Why not?

Comment: I am using auto increment function. I know it will get automatically a seriel number. But my question is How can I display the next (auto incremented) value in the "Add new employee form" before adding it.

Comment: Do you want to get the next auto increment_id from the table ?

Comment: Don't try to preempt... add the new employee and then retrieve the autoincrement number that has been added.... if you have to preempt, add a blank, get the autoincrement number, then UPDATE the blank with the form details

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker, Muthu andNiklas. I got an overall idea from all of your comments. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can't precisely predict the next auto_increment ID, even when querying the current database status (apart from exactly one user is using the application). Example: you open the form, fetch the next auto_increment ID from the DB and display 13 as the next predicted value. In the meantime, another user opens the form and saves it faster than you. The real ID of the other user's record would be 13, yours 14.

If you really want to display the used ID in your form, you need to do some kind of allocation of your record (e.g. create an empty record on opening the form and using its ID). With some kind of status field or required field you could filter those empty records in your application until they are completed and periodically purge uncompleted records. Only downside is, that it will probably give you uncontinuous IDs if users open the form without completing it (e.g. 14, 15, 18, 20, ...).

Answer (score 3):

If the serial number is set to auto_increment you could look up the next auto_increment value beforehand using:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE table_name";
$r = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Where table_name is the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Set the serial ID to AUTO_INCREMENT

Check it out

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score -2):

```
for employee_id use auto increment
```